# Reload View after UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uialertcontroller

I have a signup screen with a phone number field. 
If the user type a too short phone number, I display an UIAlertController.
After she dismisses the Alert, the user can't send her phone number again as the send button is tapped. 
Is there a way to reload the view when the alert is dismissed to make the button untapped? 
Thanks

```
    func present_alert(title:String, content : String){
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:title, message:content, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated:true)
}
```

Comment: there a way to reload the view what the use of this what you want to reload

Comment: Reload what view? What is your code for the input view? Is it a simple UIView? A UIButton? a UITableView?

Comment: If you want to know when the user clicks the 'OK' button, simply assign a handler instead of setting it to `nil`

Comment: It's a UIViewController. Here is a screenshot http://imgur.com/a/tFwvy

Comment: where you called this func present_alert(title:String, content : String)

Comment: action_signup_v2 -- is creinaated by UIbutton or UIbarbutton, can show the code of inside the `action_signup_v2

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main reason on button click you disabled the yourbutton `sender.isEnabled = false`, when ever the alert is presented again enable your button , surely works `addyourbuttonName.isEnabled = true`

if you want to clear the current textfield value then use `yourtextfield.text = ""`

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: “Simple”, message: “Simple alertView demo with Cancel and Ok.”, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: “OK”, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
print(“OK”)
 yourtextfield.text = ""
 yourtextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
 addyourbuttonName.isEnabled = true
}


alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `addyourbuttonName.isEnabled = true` for enable your button

Answer (score 0):

```
func present_alert(title:String, content:String, button:UIButton){
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:title, message:content, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated:true){
        button.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your issue the problem is that you receive your button **false** value of parameter "isEnabled". To fix that just add to your block last string:

```
buttonName.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

After click on UIAlertAction(cancel or ok), you can add some functionality in that ok or cancel method. In the final step of that method, add viewWillAppear(true) method. Then UIViewController automatically refresh.